# How to add identity column to view?

Tags: sql-server, view

Do you know any example of altering a view and add a new identity column?

Comment: basically , you mean to add new column in a table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you see the sp_help of the view, the identity column that is mentioned is nothing but the identity of the underlying table.

If you have already added the identity column in the underlying table, you just need to alter your view and add the identity column in the select stmt.

Else you need to add the identity to your table first and then edit the view to add the column in your select stmt.

Answer (score 0):

```
ALTER TABLE <table name> 
ADD COLUMN <column name> <data type> 
AFTER <after what field>
```